# Obfuscating an integer column

Tags: t-sql, encryption, obfuscation

I could have posted this to SQL forums, but I rather look for an idea or best practice, that is why I have chosen this forum.
 I have got an integer column in SQL called Payroll Number and it is unique to employee. we will be interrogating  employee information from this system via SQL views and put into another system, but we dont want payroll numbers to be appeared as they are on this system. Therefore, we need to hash those payroll numbers on SQL so that views will serve hashed user-friendly numbers.

I spent quite a lot of time reading encryption techniques in SQL, but they are using complex algorithms to hash data and produce binary. But what I am after is less complext and obfuscating a number rather than hashing.

For instance, payroll number is 6 characters long(145674), I want to be able to generate maybe 9-10 characters long integer number from this number and use it on other systems.

I had a look at XOR'ing but I need something more robust and elegant.

How do you guys do these things? Do you write your simple algorithm obfuscate your integers? I need to do this on SQL leve, what do you suggest?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Comment: I'm guessing that you need to be able to reverse the "hash", otherwise why show the number at all.  Since this is the case you are not hashing the number but encrypting it.  Subtle difference.  Encryption can change by platform.  Which one are you using?

Comment: I dont think I need to reverse it, but the algorithm that I will use need to generate same number regardless of platform, because that number will be used in other systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not hard to hash a value but it is hard to hash a value and be sure of uniqueness and have it be a number.  However, I do have a cross database solution.

Make a new table - with two columns, id (auto generated from random starting point) and payroll id.

Everytime you need to use a user externally insert them into this table.  This will give you a local unique id you can use (internally and externally) but it is not the payroll id.

In fact, if you have an internal id already (eg user id from the user table) just use that.  There is no advantage to hashing this value if it is never decoded.  However, you can use the autogen of id as your random unique hash -- it has all the properties you need.

Comment: the problem on this is that we dont have access to that Database server, it is HR database and only certain people need access to database. we are provided views, that is it.. any alteration on database requires application vendor to be involved which take ages... Do ou think XOR ing is a bad idea to do?

Comment: It is not that XOR, rot13, or base64 is bad... just that it provides NO security.  Anyone with a slight knowledge of hashing/encryption will see it right away.  Better to do something easy and clear like multiply by 10+1 and then reverse digits.  (Note you have put the 1 at the end because of the leading 0 issue.  This is not good security, but it is as good as any of these other "easy" ones and at least it is the simplest.